# Accessing MVC5 DLL in MVC 4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a component(**DLL**) that is in MVC5,DLL contains compiled views also.When I am accessing this DLL in MVC5 project I am able to call the controller,actions of this MVC5 DLL,but when I am accessing it in MVC4 project,I am getting 404 error.

Is it possible to access MVC5 DLL in MVC 4 project?

Comment: No, dll's are never forwards compatible

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly it is not possible as dll's are not backward compatible.

But as you have MVC5 dll's and want to use them in a old Project running on MVC4.

Then you need to upgrade your Project to MVC5 in order to work with dll's

You will find the complete reference on the provided link:

[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

After upgrading you can use these dll's in your project.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to add conditions to your `.csproj` file so you can compile one version for MVC 4 and one for MVC 5. It is a little involved, but if you want to support both versions of MVC it may be an option for you.

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" $(DefineConstants.Contains('MVC4')) ">
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.4.0.20715.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" $(DefineConstants.Contains('MVC5')) ">
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then we set MVC4 or MVC5 in the DefineConstants (which can be accessed on the Build tab of project properties) before compiling.

```
<DefineConstants Condition="  '$(DefineConstants)' == '' ">MVC4;NET40;</DefineConstants>
```

Note that this setting can also be changed via a build script.

We use this technique on the [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider.csproj#L67-L98) project and it works well. Unfortunately, NuGet also does not support multiple versions of MVC, so we are stuck making a package for each major version of MVC.

It is also a little tricky putting multiple versions of MVC NuGet packages into the project. We just create a separate temporary project, install a specific MVC major version, and then copy both the NuGet `\packages\` files and the entries in the `packages.config` into this project (along side one or more different versions of MVC). Putting them in this way ensures all versions of MVC are downloaded on the CI server. Although Visual Studio doesn't display the dependencies right when switching MVC versions, building the project works great.